# Exception message: no such file to load in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rubymine

I have included `test_helper.rb` under `test` in my rails application. I have even included 
`require 'test_helper'` in my `test.rb` files under `test->unit`. When I run all the test in RubyMine for the application, I get the following error:

I have the latest versions of all RubyMine 3.2, ruby 1.9.2p290 and Rails 3.1.0.

```
/Users/im/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb
Testing started at 3:19 PM ...
Work directory: /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp}
Loading files.... 
=========================================
Fail to load: /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/performance/browsing_test.rb:1
      Exception message: no such file to load -- test_helper
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/performance/browsing_test.rb:1:in `require'
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/performance/browsing_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `require'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `block in load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `each'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:101:in `<top (required)>'
        -e:1:in `load'
        -e:1:in `<main>'
Fail to load: /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb:1
      Exception message: no such file to load -- test_helper
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb:1:in `require'
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `require'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `block in load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `each'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:101:in `<top (required)>'
        -e:1:in `load'
        -e:1:in `<main>'
Fail to load: /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/helpers/users_helper_test.rb:1
      Exception message: no such file to load -- test_helper
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/helpers/users_helper_test.rb:1:in `require'
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/helpers/users_helper_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `require'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `block in load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `each'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:101:in `<top (required)>'
        -e:1:in `load'
        -e:1:in `<main>'
Fail to load: /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/post_test.rb:1
      Exception message: no such file to load -- test_helper
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/post_test.rb:4:in `require'
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/post_test.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `require'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `block in load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `each'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:101:in `<top (required)>'
        -e:1:in `load'
        -e:1:in `<main>'
Fail to load: /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/user_test.rb:1
      Exception message: no such file to load -- test_helper
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/user_test.rb:1:in `require'
        /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/unit/user_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `require'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:48:in `block in load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `each'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:40:in `load_scripts_to_object_space'
        /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:101:in `<top (required)>'
        -e:1:in `load'
        -e:1:in `<main>'
Creating sqlite :memory: database
-- create_table("posts", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0346s
-- create_table("users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0010s
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0008s
-- assume_migrated_upto_version(20110926132602, ["db/migrate"])
   -> 0.0005s
1. /Users/im/RubymineProjects/BackChannelApp/test/test_helper.rb:1

1 files were loaded.
=========================================
Searching test suites...
=========================================
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::JSON::CircularReferenceError is deprecated! Use ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::JSON::CircularReferenceError is deprecated! Use ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Fixtures is deprecated! Use ActiveRecord::Fixtures instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Fixtures is deprecated! Use ActiveRecord::Fixtures instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Fixture is deprecated! Use ActiveRecord::Fixture instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Fixture is deprecated! Use ActiveRecord::Fixture instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
Test suite #1: ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

Ignored because it is default rails empty test suite
=========================================
Test suite #1: ActiveSupport::TestCase

Ignored because it is default rails empty test suite
=========================================
Test suite #1: ActionController::TestCase

Ignored because it is default rails empty test suite
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::SecureRandom is deprecated! Use SecureRandom instead. (called from is_test_case_class? at /Applications/RubyMine 3.2.4.app/rb/testing/runner/tunit_in_folder_runner.rb:80)
=========================================
Test suite #1: ActiveRecord::TestCase

Ignored because it is default rails empty test suite
=========================================
0 test suites, 0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors


Process finished with exit code 0
```

What am I missing? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test_helper.rb is located within the test directory. You are running the tests from the root directory, which means the path to the file is wrong. Try running your tests from the test directory.

If you want to run your tests from the root directory, you would have to change this to `require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'test_helper.rb')`, where FILE is the path to the file that contains this line (your test case), and the rest is the path of test_helper.rb, relative to that file. This way, where you run the test from is irrelevant.

Comment: Please @Shaun how is it possible, that i can run tests with rake test, and test_helper is found without problem, but if i want to run tests with rubymine, it is not possible, till i add your require feature?

Answer (score 2):

In my situation (RM 7.1 / Win7 / Rails 3.0), I had to do the following:

> Add "-Itest" at the beginning of "Ruby arguments"

Note: Changing the working directory to 'test' didn't work for me.
Source: https://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5490675#5490675